# VueJS Dynamic Slot parameter reactivity

Tags: vue.js

I have a component contains dynamic slots. I tried to watch the dynamic parameters for those slots. But seems those parameters are not reactive.

Following is the example, also available in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jianwu/1jLqkpyz/12/)

I noticed only if the parameter is bound to an array (**p2**), it's reactive. Otherwise for simple value (**p1**) is not reactive.

And in the "**mounted**", I saved the $slots to this.slots. I noticed, initially, **$slots===slots** is true, but once I change the p1 or p2, they are no longer equal. It seems every time parameter changes, the whole **$slot** object tree will be recreated. And **$slots** object is not reactive.

Is there a better way to watch those parameters without wrapper them inside array.

```
<div id="app">
  p1: <input v-model='p1'/><br>
  p2: <input v-model='p2[0]'/><br>
  <test>
    <div slot='s1' :p1='p1' :p2='p2'></div>
  </test>
</div>

<template id='test-template'>
  <div style='background-color:red'>
    slots === $slots: {{slots===$slots}}<br>
    $slots.s1[0].data.attrs: {{$slots.s1[0].data.attrs}}<br>
    p1:{{p1}}<br>
    p2:{{p2}}
    <slot name='s1'></slot>
  </div>
</template>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    'test': {
      data() { 
        return {
          slots: null,
          p1:null,
          p2:null,
        }; 
      },
      template: `#test-template`,
      mounted() {
        this.slots = this.$slots;
        this.p1 = this.$slots.s1[0].data.attrs.p1;
        this.p2 = this.$slots.s1[0].data.attrs.p2;
      }
    },
  },

  data: {
    p1: 'v1',
    p2: ['v2'],
  }
})
```

Comment: 1. This feels like a XY problem to me, http://xyproblem.info/. 2. The array will be passed by reference so changes in one place will be seen elsewhere, nothing to do with reactivity. 3. Changes to slots will trigger rendering so the `beforeUpdate` hook would seem a natural place to do whatever you need to do.